# How to calculate orbital velocity of binary star?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, binary-star, python, velocity, n-body-simulations

I am trying to simulate the Alpha Centauri AB System. I built the simulation, it works flawlessly when trying to simulate our solar system, and I am now trying to simulate the AB System. I found all the measurements, but I can't seem the simulate it properly. I tried calculating the positions and velocities of the two bodies by using this script I wrote:

```
G = 6.67430e-11 # gravitational constant
pi = 3.1415926535 # pi
au =  1.495978707e11 # astronomical unit
solar_mass = 1.989e30 # solar mass

m1 = 1.0788 * solar_mass # mass of a
m2 = 0.9092 * solar_mass # mass of b
m = m1 + m2

d = 1/0.75081 # distance in parsecs, 1/parallax

a = 17.493 * au * d # large semi-axis in au, from distance * semi-axis
a1 = m2 * a/m # large semi-axis of a
a2 = m1 * a/m # large semi-axis of b

e = 0.51947 # eccentricity

r1 = a1 * (1+e) # distance from barycenter at apastron of a in meters
r2 = a2 * (1+e) # distance from barycenter at apastron of b in meters
r = r1 + r2


def func():
    print("object 1 pos: {}".format(r1/au)) # distance in au
    print("object 1 vel: {}".format((G * m2 * ((2/r1) - (1/a1)))**0.5)) # velocity at apastron of a
    print("object 2 pos: {}".format(r2/au)) # distance in au
    print("object 2 vel: {}".format((G * m1 * ((2/r2) - (1/a2)))**0.5)) # velocity at apastron of b

func()
```

This is the result I get from calculating position and velocities using the script and then simulating it:

[image: Simulation of Alpha Centauri AB with calculated parameters, using the script above]

The problem with this is, that it should result in a stable orbit, but instead they just go wandering off. I realize that I may have calculated the escape velocities by accident, but using the same formula, to calculate the orbital velocities of the planets of our solar system, seems to work fine.

I am really frustrated right now as it just won't work, but I really need it to. I would appreciate any help on this topic. :)

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Can you be more specific? It would be helpful if you showed your result and commented on why it is not what you were expecting

Comment: You are not showing how you have assigned initial position and initial velocities, so it may be hard to tell why it is not working. You could try lowering the velocities and see what happens

Comment: This line seems fishy to me: `a = 17.493 * au * d # large semi-axis in au, from distance * semi-axis`. The value `d` is in units of parsecs (assume your parallax is in units of arcseconds, which you don't specify), but I assume `17.493 * au` has units of meters. Definitely a unit issue there. And in any case I don't know what "large semi-axis" is, but whatever it is, you seem to be calculating something that has units of $length^2$ which is probably not what you want. Double check your equations and units.

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you manage to fix it?